# MinifiedEnabled breaks app in release mode

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

The issue i'm having is only occuring in release mode.
When the process reach an async task the app always stop unexpectedly with this error :

```
02-21 21:07:02.913  13084-13409/com.dimtion.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.dimtion.app, PID: 13084
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/a/b/m
        at a.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.di.b(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.di.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.c.ae.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at a.a.a.j.e(Unknown Source)
        at com.dimtion.app.g.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.dimtion.app.g.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

In the `doInBackground()` method there is only a Jsoup connection and parsing  :

```
try {
    Connection.Response loginPage = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .cookies(coockies)
        .data("login", username)
        .data("password", password)
        .data("token", token)
        .data("returnurl", url_app)
        .execute();

    Document document = loginPage.parse();
    Element logoutElement = document.body().select("a[href=?do=logout]").first();
    logoutElement.attr("href"); // If this fails, you're not connected
} catch (IOException   e) {
    this.error = 1;
    return false;
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    this.error = 3;
    return false;
}
return true;
```

The matter is that because the code is compressed there is no way to put break points to debug the code. But I know this is comming from the option MinifiedEnabled because without it, the app work fine.

Comment: Google any library you're using with "proguard" (like "jsoup proguard") and add found rules to your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Comment: Could you post your proguard rules?

Comment: I haven't edited the proguard rules so it is still the default ones, you are probably right, there is probably something to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the the two people who opened my eyes, I forgot to edit my pro guard rules.
So I just added in `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
```

[Here where the solution is from](http://www.jormula.com/dev/2013/01/29/tutorial-how-to-solve-force-close-crash-using-jsoup-with-proguard-in-android/)